# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: No further installation of packets and updates, because of Python Version Problems - How to clean

Tags: 20.04, package-management, updates, python, dependencies

---*An Update (further Details) are given at the bottom*---

I have done successfully an In-distro-upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 onto 20.04 LTS. This was already a while ago and the machine is my daily working client. At this time i was able to apply Ubuntu updates. I have a lot of packets installed. The most were installed by the classical packet management system apt-get.

In the meantime i have installed some packets, which are requiring different python versions. Now I run in deep problems, because since this, I cant't install anything on my system.

I've read a lot of posts, which are addressing this python chaos without a final solution. And I'am aware for the future, that I have to use pip or docker. So I will do this.

But at the moment I rely on my daily working client and there is no chance to make it new.

Is there a way to set up a stable, native state for python as if I made a new installation (a kind of reset state)? Also, if after that, some python based user programs doesn't run.

I can't localize, when this problems came up. At the following I present some analysis to my system.

I have seen, that some stopped programm installations with the packet management (apt-get install) will overwrite the system wide /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7, but this is denied.
I strongly suspect that this is causing through the python-gtk2 dependency?!, because this error/message a few weeks ago was alone. With trying to solve the problem i get this new message for python-enchant.

Many thanks in advance for helpful ideas.

***------My System (sorry this is a german localization)***

```
user@mymachine:~$ **lsb_release -a**
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

user@mymachine:~$ **sudo snap list**

```
Name                Version          Revision  Tracking       Herausgeber  Hinweise
core                16-2.49.2        10958     latest/stable  canonical?   core
core18              20210309         1997      latest/stable  canonical?   base
go                  1.16.3           7360      latest/stable  mwhudson     classic
gtk-common-themes   0.1-52-gb92ac40  1515      latest/stable  canonical?   -
gtk2-common-themes  0.1              13        latest/stable  canonical?   -
```

***------Usage of python within the actual session***

user@mymachine: ~$ **ps aux | grep python**

```
root        1213  0.0  0.0  39732 14776 ?        Ss   Mai02   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root        1601  0.0  0.1 118480 16892 ?        Ssl  Mai02   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
user          3120  0.0  0.1 435708 27452 ?        Sl   Mai02   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet
user          3125  0.0  0.1  65492 32024 ?        S    Mai02   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
user          3245  0.0  0.1 360956 28980 ?        Sl   Mai02   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-tray
user         22367  0.0  0.0   9412   672 pts/4    S+   10:39   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

***------After a sudo apt-upgrade or packet installation via *.deb or sudo apt-get install I get a dependency problem message:***

```
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:

 python-enchant : Hängt ab von: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                  Hängt ab von: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-gtk2 : Hängt ab von: python (>= 2.7)
               Hängt ab von: python (< 2.8)
 python-gtksourceview2 : Hängt ab von: python (>= 2.7)
                         Hängt ab von: python (< 2.8)
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt --fix-broken install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

***------Python analysis***
user@mymachine:~$**dpkg -l | grep libpython.*minimal**

```
ii  libpython2.7-minimal:amd64                    2.7.18-1~20.04                        amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
ii  libpython3.7-minimal:amd64                    3.7.5-2~19.10ubuntu1                  amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.7)
ii  libpython3.8-minimal:amd64                    3.8.5-1~20.04                         amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.8)
```

user@mymachine:~$ **sudo  apt-cache --installed  -i --recurse rdepends   libpython3.8-minimal | grep "^  " | sort -u |xargs apt-mark auto**

```
apport wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
aptdaemon wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
apturl-common wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
command-not-found wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
gdb wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
gir1.2-peas-1.0 wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
gnome-software-plugin-snap wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
ibus wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
Markierung für ibus:i386 kann nicht gesetzt werden, da es nicht installiert ist.
language-selector-common wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
Markierung für libglib2.0-dev-bin:i386 kann nicht gesetzt werden, da es nicht installiert ist.
libpeas-1.0-0 wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
libpurple-bin wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
libpython3.8 wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
libpython3.8-stdlib wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
libpython3-stdlib wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
libsmbclient wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
netplan.io wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
networkd-dispatcher wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
onboard-common wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
onboard-data wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
printer-driver-foo2zjs-common wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
printer-driver-postscript-hp wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3.8 wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3.8-minimal wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-apport wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-apsw wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-apt wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-aptdaemon wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-cairo wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-cffi-backend wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-chm wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-commandnotfound wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-crypto wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-cryptography wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-cssselect wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-cups wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-cupshelpers wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-dbus wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-debianbts wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-distupgrade wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-gdbm wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-gi wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-gi-cairo wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-gpg wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-html5-parser wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-ibus-1.0 wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-keyring wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-launchpadlib wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-lazr.restfulclient wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-ldb wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-lxml wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-minimal wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-msgpack wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-nacl wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-netifaces wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-numpy wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-oauthlib wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-odf wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-pil wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-psutil wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-pycurl wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-pymacaroons wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-pyqt5.qtsvg wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-pysimplesoap wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-regex wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-renderpm wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-reportlab wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-reportlab-accel wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-samba wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-sane wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-secretstorage wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-setuptools wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-simplejson wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-software-properties wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-systemd wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-talloc wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-tdb wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-tk wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-uno wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-update-manager wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-urwid wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-webob wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python3-yaml wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python-apt-common wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
python-odf-tools wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
samba-common-bin wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
samba-dsdb-modules wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
samba-libs wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
system-config-printer-common wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
system-config-printer-udev wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
ubuntu-advantage-tools wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
unattended-upgrades wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
virtualbox-qt wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
xserver-xorg wurde bereits auf automatisch installiert gesetzt.
Markierung für xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 kann nicht gesetzt werden, da es nicht installiert ist.
E: Could not create temporary file for /var/lib/apt/extended_states - mkstemp (13: Keine Berechtigung)
E: Temporäres StateFile /var/lib/apt/extended_states konnte nicht geschrieben werden.
```

user@mymachine: ~$ **apt-cache rdepends -i --installed --recurse python2 | grep -v " " | sort -u**

```
calibre
font-manager
gimp
meld
nautilus-dropbox
ocrfeeder
python2
python-apsw
python-cairo
python-cffi-backend
python-crypto
python-cryptography
python-dbus
python-gi
python-gobject
python-gobject-2
python-gtk2
python-gtksourceview2
python-libxml2
python-lxml
python-netifaces
python-numpy
python-openssl
python-pil
python-simplejson
python-sip
python-tk
python-yaml
scribus
scribus-data
```

user@mymachine: ~$ **ls -al /usr/bin/python***

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Feb 24 14:48 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Feb 24  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3629032 Aug  4  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Aug  4  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mär 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5102632 Apr 19  2020 /usr/bin/python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5102632 Apr 19  2020 /usr/bin/python3.7m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5486352 Jul 28  2020 /usr/bin/python3.8
```

**--- Update 01 ---**

Hi,
i give the complete output of sudo apt -f install here:

If you can see, there ist a locking of the system wide python version (2.7.17-1), which have to be updated with this package: python-is-python2_2.7.17-4_all.deb

```
user@mymachine: ~$ sudo apt -f install
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Abhängigkeiten werden korrigiert ... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  gcc-9-base:i386 geoip-database libapt-pkg5.90 libart-2.0-2 libbind9-161
  libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0
  libboost-thread1.67.0 libbrlapi0.6 libcodec2-0.8.1 libdns-export1104
  libdns1104 libdns1109 libdvdread4 libevent-2.1-6 libevent-core-2.1-6
  libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libexiv2-14 libffi6 libffi6:i386 libfluidsynth1
  libgeoip1 libgnome-2-0 libgnome-desktop-3-18 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
  libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0
  libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgsoap-2.8.75
  libgspell-1-1 libgutenprint-common libgutenprint9 libhogweed4
  libhogweed4:i386 libicu63 libicu63:i386 libidl-2-0 libilmbase23 libiptc0
  libirs161 libisc-export1100 libisc1100 libisc1105 libisccc161 libisccfg163
  libisl21 libjte1 libllvm9 liblouis17 liblwres161 libmypaint-1.3-0 libmysofa0
  libnettle6 libnettle6:i386 libnfs12 liboauth0 libopenexr23 liborbit-2-0
  liborbit2 liborcus-0.14-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libplymouth4 libpoppler90
  libpython-stdlib libpython3.7 libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib
  libqpdf21 libusbmuxd4 libwnck-common libwnck22 libx265-176
  linux-headers-5.3.0-62 linux-headers-5.3.0-62-generic
  linux-image-5.3.0-62-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-62-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-62-generic node-is-builtin-module node-node-uuid
  printer-driver-gutenprint python-blinker python-certifi python-crypto
  python-httplib2 python-idna python-minimal python-pyasn1
  python-pyasn1-modules python-tz python-xdg python3-asn1crypto python3-nacl
  python3-pymacaroons python3.7 python3.7-minimal
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden installiert:
  python-is-python2
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  python-is-python2
0 aktualisiert, 1 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 220 nicht aktualisiert.
5 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 2.496 B an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 10,2 kB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
(Lese Datenbank ... 376668 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../python-is-python2_2.7.17-4_all.deb ...
Entpacken von python-is-python2 (2.7.17-4) ...
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/python-is-pytho
n2_2.7.17-4_all.deb (--unpack):
 Versuch, »/usr/bin/python« zu überschreiben, welches auch in Paket python-minim
al 2.7.17-1 ist
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-is-python2_2.7.17-4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**--- Update 02 ---**

How can i change the installation canditate (2.7.12-1~16.04). This could be the problem because it's a invalid source?

```
sudo apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installiert:           (keine)
  Installationskandidat: 2.7.12-1~16.04
  Versionstabelle:
     2.7.17-1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.12-1~16.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Try; sudo apt - f install

Comment: Thanks tatojo, I have done this in past sometimes. This is the output error message: 
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/python-is-python2_2.7.17-4_all.deb (--unpack):

Comment: In this case obviosely the command
 sudo apt -f install or sudo apt --fix-broken install
doesn't have an effect.

Comment: I've given the complete output in an article update. There's a dependency problem within these two python versions 2.7.17-1 and 2.7.17-4.

Comment: Did you try: sudo apt autoremove?

Comment: Yes, in this case i get the same output as shwon in my "main article, code window 4" notice (unfullfilled dependency of these python versions in relation to python-gtk2 and python-gtksourceview2.

Comment: The newest Python2 for 20.04 in the Ubuntu repositories is 2.7.17-2ubuntu4. Seems like you are getting Python2 packages from some non-Ubuntu source. That is a common cause of the problem you are encountering. Stop using that source and revert to the Ubuntu repository version.

Comment: Hello user535733, do you have an idea, how to change the wrong installation canditate (see Update 02 notice)